# Tidying data: from cell containing vector to column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a tibble that contains vectors of *doubles* for motifs (e.g `motif_1` and `motif_2`):

```
table <- tibble(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                motif_1 = list(c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10))),
                motif_2 = list(c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10)), c(runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 10))))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     ID motif_1   motif_2  
  <dbl> <list>    <list>   
1     1 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
2     2 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
3     3 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
4     4 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
5     5 <dbl [5]> <dbl [5]>
```

What I would like to do is creating columns in the number regarding the length of vectors (always 5, so `P1`...`P5`) to which would be assigned values of the vectors correspond to the particular position in the vector.

What in overall would lead to this output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      ID motif      P1    P2    P3    P4    P5
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 motif_1  2.61  4.19 0.182  4.26 5.60 
 2     2 motif_1  5.88  5.24 5.97   3.26 0.390
 3     3 motif_1  6.86  1.25 9.98   4.56 2.93 
 4     4 motif_1  3.02  8.99 7.33   8.12 4.18 
 5     5 motif_1  2.40  6.61 6.35   8.42 0.202
 6     1 motif_2  2.39  7.12 7.61   3.83 0.506
 7     2 motif_2  5.20  3.09 5.53   1.52 6.05 
 8     3 motif_2  3.97  2.90 5.94   6.85 2.99 
 9     4 motif_2  8.37  5.35 3.84   1.88 0.358
10     5 motif_2  6.53  2.78 8.59   1.57 4.90
```

To be more specific, while considering only 1st row of the input table:

```
FROM:
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     ID motif_1                           motif_2  
  <dbl> <list>                            <list>   
1     1 c(2.61, 4.19, 0.182, 4.26, 5.60)  <dbl [5]>

TO:
    ID   motif    P1    P2    P3    P4    P5
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 motif_1  2.61  4.19 0.182  4.26 5.60 
 2     1 motif_2  ...
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

table %>%
  unnest(cols = starts_with('motif')) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, name) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('P', row_number())) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value)

#    ID name       P1    P2    P3    P4      P5
#   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1 motif_1  1.52 1.39  2.33   4.66 2.66   
# 2     1 motif_2  4.40 7.54  6.29   7.10 0.00625
# 3     2 motif_1  8.58 0.458 4.42   7.99 1.22   
# 4     2 motif_2  4.75 2.20  3.80   6.13 3.52   
# 5     3 motif_1  5.61 2.07  1.28   7.53 8.95   
# 6     3 motif_2  1.11 2.44  6.68   4.18 7.88   
# 7     4 motif_1  3.74 6.65  0.948  3.84 2.74   
# 8     4 motif_2  1.03 4.35  9.85   8.93 8.86   
# 9     5 motif_1  8.15 4.49  8.10   8.12 7.94   
#10     5 motif_2  1.75 1.31  6.53   3.44 6.57
```